# Cannot access docker container from outside the OS that is running it

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, docker, linux-networking

I'm not an heavy user of Unix based systems. And I have some trouble opening a server's port (80) to the public and redirect it to a running container.

So basically, I have a running container on a running Ubuntu server (IP 167.86.106.109), the IP of the container is 127.0.200.1 (and port 80 is open).

Running `TELNET 127.0.200.1 80` on 167.86.106.109 and I'm able to do a GET that return 200. From outside I have a timeout

I've done the following but I still cannot access 167.86.106.109 on port 80 from outside (timeout error) :

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DNAT --to 127.0.200.1:80`

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE`

`iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DNAT --to 127.0.200.1:80`

`iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules`

`ufw allow http`

Obviously, I've done something wrong, but what ?

Output of `docker ps`:

```
2f7617d72299   polk-auction-ui:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   52 minutes ago   Up 52 minutes   127.0.200.1:80->80/tcp   polk-auction-ui
```

This is on Ubuntu 20.04 (64 Bit). The container is a Docker container (v 20.10.14)

More info about my current setup:

The OS (IP 167.86.106.109) is running on a VPS, the docker container I want to reach from outside is running a nginx with the following configuration:

```json
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;
    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    
    server {
      listen 80;
      location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        #try_files $uri =404;
      }
    }
}
```

The result of `ufw status verbose` :

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
30333                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
30333 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

The output of `iptables -L -v -n` : (A lot is coming from docker itself)

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 37 packets, 2168 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
32669 4524K f2b-sshd   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
2374K 1737M ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2374K 1737M ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 274K   16M ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 262K   16M ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 262K   16M ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 262K   16M ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 167M  118G DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 167M  118G DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 888K  166M ACCEPT     all  --  *      br-4c0567f529d0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
19186 1150K DOCKER     all  --  *      br-4c0567f529d0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-4c0567f529d0 !br-4c0567f529d0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
19186 1150K ACCEPT     all  --  br-4c0567f529d0 br-4c0567f529d0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  51M   59G ACCEPT     all  --  *      br-56fce7b8bc16  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 3433  971K DOCKER     all  --  *      br-56fce7b8bc16  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  39M 3429M ACCEPT     all  --  br-56fce7b8bc16 !br-56fce7b8bc16  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 3397  969K ACCEPT     all  --  br-56fce7b8bc16 br-56fce7b8bc16  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  42M   53G ACCEPT     all  --  *      br-9316082e3f65  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 3397  969K DOCKER     all  --  *      br-9316082e3f65  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  33M 2699M ACCEPT     all  --  br-9316082e3f65 !br-9316082e3f65  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 3397  969K ACCEPT     all  --  br-9316082e3f65 br-9316082e3f65  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
37132  233M ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
13310 1453K ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1835K   83M ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
1835K   83M ufw-before-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 2843  253K ufw-after-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 2843  253K ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 2843  253K ufw-reject-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 2843  253K ufw-track-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER (4 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-9316082e3f65 br-9316082e3f65  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:8080
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-56fce7b8bc16 br-56fce7b8bc16  0.0.0.0/0            172.19.0.2           tcp dpt:8080
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-4c0567f529d0 br-4c0567f529d0  0.0.0.0/0            172.20.0.2           tcp dpt:3306
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-4c0567f529d0 br-4c0567f529d0  0.0.0.0/0            172.20.0.3           tcp dpt:8080
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-56fce7b8bc16 br-56fce7b8bc16  0.0.0.0/0            172.19.0.5           tcp dpt:30333
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-9316082e3f65 br-9316082e3f65  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:30333
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-56fce7b8bc16 br-56fce7b8bc16  0.0.0.0/0            172.19.0.3           tcp dpt:80

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  br-4c0567f529d0 !br-4c0567f529d0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0         
  39M 3429M DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  br-56fce7b8bc16 !br-56fce7b8bc16  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0         
  33M 2699M DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  br-9316082e3f65 !br-9316082e3f65  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0         
13310 1453K DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 167M  118G RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (4 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      br-4c0567f529d0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      br-56fce7b8bc16  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      br-9316082e3f65  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  73M 6129M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 167M  118G RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
28666 4185K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
   81  4104 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
11583  599K ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
12797  753K LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 5083  453K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
41195 5355K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 4634  827K ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
 4634  827K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
 4586  357K ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
 211K   74M ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
1823K  109M ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
1823K  109M ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 5089  453K ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
1722K   74M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 2488  227K ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 3643  763K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
  671 48807 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1823K  109M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
    0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
11664  603K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  346 43729 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
 1599  153K ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 2237  132K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
 2240  114K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
1663K  100M ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:30333
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:30333

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

EDIT:

The docker-compose used :

```yaml
version: "3.8"

networks:
    polkadot:
        external: true
    kusama:
        external: true

services: 
    polk-auction-ui:
        image: polk-auction-ui:latest
        container_name: polk-auction-ui
        ports:
            - "127.0.200.1:80:80"
        networks:
            - polkadot
            - kusama
```

image is built like this :

```yaml
# Build step
FROM node:14 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . ./
RUN yarn build:prod

# Run step
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Why not publish the port? `-p 80:$containerport`

Comment: @BMitch Can you expend on this ? Sorry, I'm not sure to understand how to publish the port. Note that the port of the container is already mapped on port 80 of the host

Comment: We need to see how you run the container. Include that command (or yaml file) in your question).

Comment: I've edited the question to add the docker-compose file and the Dockerfile used to built the image (if that matters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`127.0.0.0/8` is the loopback interface, aka localhost. To publish on all interfaces, you can remove the IP address from the published port:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

networks:
    polkadot:
        external: true
    kusama:
        external: true

services: 
    polk-auction-ui:
        image: polk-auction-ui:latest
        container_name: polk-auction-ui
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        networks:
            - polkadot
            - kusama
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver!